# Ohm's law when there's no resistance

Tags: resistance, ohms-law

ohm's law says that V = I*R

And so
I = V/R

But what happens if we have a circuit with 0 resistance?
That would make everything else 0. What does that mean?

Comment: no, it would make current infinite.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on the faulty premise that something divided by 0 is 0 not infinity.

Comment: @RoyC, 0 divided by 0 is 73. Prove me wrong.

Comment: @ScottSedmam no,it wouldn't.  It would force the voltage drop to zero, or the material would cease superconducting.

Comment: @The Photon  0 divided by 0 is undefined in formal mathematics however there are good arguments (a couple of different methods of limits) for it to be either 0 or +/-1. Moving from pure mathematics to any practical circuit where you have a near 0 resistance and some voltage the current is very large.

Comment: @RoyC, It isn't always 0 or 1 (or any particular value) \$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{73\sin x}{x}}\$ is one way to write 0/0 with a value of 73.

Comment: Ohm's law doesn't apply to everything, it only applies to resistive elements. Diodes, LEDs, transistors, capacitors, and inductors are governed by different models.

Comment: No that breaks down to 0/0 x73 at the limit. This is the same fallacy as saying. 1=73 because 0 x 1=0 x 73..

Comment: In such circumstances use the limit as \$R\rightarrow 0\$. Clearly, a 0 ohm conductor could carry a current of any value with 0 volt across its ends. Every time we draw a circuit diagram we assume there is no voltage drop across the conductors joining components.

Comment: @RoyC, How about \$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(73x)}{x}\$, then? I'm not making any claim that 1=73. I'm just saying that when we encounter 0/0 we're most often talking about some kind of limit, and the value of that limit can be anything, not just 0 or 1.

Comment: What will you give as answer if your math teacher ask you to solve 1/0 ? "Infinite"? No you are wrong. It is "undefined". https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero

Answer (score 3):

Only superconductors have zero resistance. Typically that happens under rather special conditions, such as very low temperature and special materials.

But zero resistance (and it *really* is zero, as far as anyone has been able to determine) does **not** mean zero impedance. If you connect a voltage source across a superconductor a voltage will appear due to the inductance. The current will start off at zero and increase. When it reaches the critical current Jc the superconductor will go normal and will no longer have zero resistance. If you short the superconductor before that point, the curent will circulate in the conductor forever, causing a magnetic field.

Comment: It is in theory. How can somebody check forever?

Comment: @user263983 They have made empirical measurements over a number of years and the current does not decay to ppm level of measurement.

Answer (score 2):

First, in the real world only superconductors have 0 resistance, and they're not something you see in everyday circuits.

> That would make everything else 0.

Not necessarily. If \$V\$ is also zero, then the current can be finite. Or, if the voltage is non-zero then the current goes to infinity, not to zero.

You have to consider the rest of the circuit your 0-ohm resistor is connected to to find out if it will continue to supply an ever-increasing current to the resistor, or if it will provide a limited current for some reason. (Practically, it will always provide a limited, finite, current)

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question because it demonstrates the limits of modelling.

Ohm's law is often abused as an idealized model of the relationship between V,I and R. It is often correct, which is why sometimes it is habitually and successfully applied, even when it shouldn't.

Here's why.

Consider R=V/I and I=V/R. Both are mathematically problematic if I=0 or R=0 respectively. I think this is clear to everyone, and it's the OP's correct starting point.

Can they be theoretically attained? Sure, in the math simply set I=0 or set R=0.

Can those values be practically attained? Maybe. You can argue about superconductors and cryogenic temperatures (R=0) and ideal insulators (I=0) but I think this misses the point.

The issue is not the quantity of any of the 3 values, but understanding when their triad relationship holds, whether in theory or in practice.

Take the law in the form I=V/R, which says that if you know V and R you can calculate I. It also says that with R approaching 0, the current approaches infinity.

This is where the law as a model shows its limitations: the law does not model the current as a result of a supplied voltage, it describes the current as a result of a measured voltage.

The "V" in V/I is not the supplied voltage, but the measured voltage, even if a supply is applied to the R directly. Although the "V" is an equation "input" value, it is an effect not a cause. At minimum you need Kirchhoff's circuit laws in a larger context to describe the interrelationship between V and I.

For the current to increase indefinitely, the measured voltage has to increase indefinitely, and there is no supply that can accomplish that. That limitation is  not part of the law. It's not a shortcoming, it's simply not in it.

So to the question

> But what happens if we have a circuit with 0 resistance? That would make everything else 0.

Correct, V must be 0 and will be 0. Why 0 and not "undefined", per the math? Because the math (and the law) do not describe the whole picture around the circuit section where it is applied.

> What does that mean?

The law is correct but it does not describe other interrelationships between V and I.